# Where can I find what controls the behavior of Ctrl + Alt + Backspace?

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce

The usual place, `/home/username/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`, shows nothing for this combo, but pressing it clearly does something. I'm unsure if it reboots X or just logs me out. Where can I find what Ctrl + Alt + Backspace is set up to trigger on my machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a direct answer, and All I know Ctrl+Alt+Backspace kills X Server. I checked the origin and found useful references ONLY, you may need a +50 year old dinasour for this topic because I'm only a 30y old dinosaur. Hope it helps!

[Control-Alt-Delete or "three-finger salute"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Alt-Delete) is a soft reboot function via keyboard was originally designed by David Bradley.

and check,

[Magic SysRq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

> Before the advent of journaled filesystems a common use of the magic SysRq key was to perform a safe reboot of a Linux computer which has otherwise locked up (abbr. REISUB), which avoided a risk of filesystem corruption. With modern filesystems, this practice is discouraged, offering no upsides over straight re`B`oot.

Another past use was to kill a frozen graphical program, as the X Windows System used to have complete control over graphical mode and input devices.

#### Configuration

> The feature is controlled both by a compile-time option in the kernel configuration, CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ, and a sysctl kernel parameter, kernel.sysrq.

> On newer kernels (since 2.6.12[5]), it is possible to have more fine-grained control over how the magic SysRq key can be used.[6] On these machines, the number written to `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` can be `0`, `1`, or a number greater than 1 which is a bitmask indicating which features to allow. On Ubuntu this is set at boot time to the value defined in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf`

### Other ways to invoke Magic SysRq

> While the magic SysRq key was originally implemented as part of the kernel's keyboard handler for debugging, the functionality has been also exposed via the proc filesystem and is commonly used to provide extended management capabilities to headless and remote systems. From user space programs (such as a command line shell), SysRq may be accessed by writing to `/proc/sysrq-trigger` (e.g., `echo s > /proc/sysrq-trigger`).[1]

> Many embedded systems have no attached keyboard, but instead use a serial console for text input/output to the running system. It is possible to invoke a Magic SysRq feature over a serial console by sending a serial break signal, followed by the desired key. The method of sending a break is dependent on the terminal program or hardware used to connect to the serial console. A sysctl option needs to be set to enable this function.[7]

As well look for [X display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager) and [X Windows System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System)

Answer (score 2):

It's in `/etc/default/keyboard`. The relevant line is `XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is not in the users config files is that the "zap X server" functionality is a functionality of the X server. I.e. the combination shall work even in the login screen, before any user settings are loaded (I used that combination often back in the day when I had to write and test my own modelines...).

This functionality was hardcoded since the dawn of the X server, just as Ctrl+Alt+Delete was hardcoded into the depths of certain OS as a quick method of ending a failed test run. As such, it tends to not come up in any list of "active key combinations". To directly answer your question: The key combination "Ctrl+Alt+Backspace" just kills the X server or does nothing.

If it kills the X server, the display manager (lightdm is often used here) may automatically start the X server again, depending on its configuration. If it does nothing to the X server, it might be configured to do something else, but that is now the responsibility of the Desktop Environment configuration of the user.

Nowadays, the functionality is implemented as an action named `Terminate_Server`, `SA_TerminateServer` or `terminate` (depending on the subsystem whose docs you read), emitted by the XKB ("X Keyboard") subsystem and interpreted by the X server.

Therefore, the setting controlling the key combination is in the system-wide keyboard configuration in `/etc/default/keyboard` (as J. Mini already answered; I also did not find an option to set it to anything else than `ctrl_alt_bksp` or unset); and the setting whether that action is interpreted at all is in the [X server configuration files](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml) (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf*`):

> *Option "DontZap" "boolean"*
>
> > This disallows the use of the Terminate_Server XKB action (usually on Ctrl+Alt+Backspace, depending on XKB options). This action is normally used to terminate the Xorg server. When this option is enabled, the action has no effect. Default: off.